# How to Use MediaStore to display all images in GridView

Tags: android, gridview, cursor, mediastore

I need a little help in trying to figure out a problem that I am having. I have an application that will query all the images on the phone and display them in a GridView. I was able to do this and populate the list. The problem is when I am accessing the list and getting information from the items from a query. The cursor is telling me that the item has a file path of

/mnt/sdcard/images/media/file.jpg

but the path is only

/sdcard/images/media/file.jpg

This is the code I used to populate the list.

```
        // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
        // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
        //returns the cursor that checks the sdcard for Thumbnail id's
              cursor = managedQuery( 
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, 
                // Which columns to return
                null,
                // Return all rows
                null,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
              // Get the column index of the Thumbnails Image ID
              columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);
```

The items DO ACTUALLY display but the path is wrong when I retrieve them from another cursor.
??????
I am a bit lost.

I have used it in emulator and on my physical device. Same problem.
I get an ERROR stating that the path is NULL and the program crashed.

Is there a way that I can get the MediaStore to query the EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI and give the correct path I need?
Also, when I used it on my physical phone, the query when to the first directory on my sdcard with images then stopped, and way for it to query more directories?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` ?

Also `managedQuery()` is deprecated, use `getContentResolver().query()`.