# Image picker like in Whatsapp, facebook

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, mediastore

I'm trying to implement an image picker like in whatsapp where you select 'Gallery' and it opens its own custom Gallery(not system/os gallery) and then it displays the Thumbnails with all the folders. Then we click on 1 of them and it displays images in those folders/albums and then we can pick the image. I'm trying to implement the very same thing in my app.

So what I've tried and done till now:
I know MediaStore content provider is required for this, and this is the first time I'm working with Content Providers. I've gone through many posts and articles but not getting how to or what to use to implement this thing. Most of the articles are too old and using SimpleCursorAdapter while I'm trying to implement this thing using RecyclerView GridView.

Posts I've followed :

[Post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8684608/how-to-use-mediastore-to-display-all-images-in-gridview)

[Post2](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/11/list-mediastoreimagesthumbnails-in.html)

[Post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23686024/android-how-to-get-all-folders-with-photos)

The 3rd one is the best one but the answer is around 5 years old. 
There is no use of posting my code here as I've tried a lot of things but not got exactly what I'm trying to implement. 
So any references or guidance towards how to implement this would be great. I just need the proper things which I should look into and explore more as the MediaStore official documentation is not so detailed.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: @Aradhna Yupz long back.

Comment: How did you implement it?

Answer (score 1):

I know it is a bit late to answer this question, but I thought I should add my 2 cents, for anyone else that may run into this thread.

There is a great 3rd party library called [PixImagePicker](https://github.com/akshay2211/PixImagePicker). This library is a replica of the WhatsApp style image picker. At the time of writing this post, this library supports selecting one or more images. The creator of the library has mentioned plans of supporting selection of videos (this has not been implemented yet). Out of all the media pickers I have seen online, this one seems to have the least reported issues.

Answer (score 0):

PIXIMAGEPICKER - Whatsapp like Image Picker

Suppose I selected 5 images from gallery using this picker & it populated 5 images in recylerview

Now I deselect all 5 images this time
Expected Result - Deselect & Remove all image path from returnvalue(arraylist)

Actual Result - Deselect All Images; **Images removed from array is one less than image selected (Issue)**